# Why does my one decryption method run way faster than another?

Tags: java, android, outputstream, des

I created encryption decryption methods to encrypt images and videos. I'm partially encrypting the videos, 1 MB to be exact.  The more complicated decrypt method take way to long to decrypts the content on the android device. However the img_decrypt doesn take long at all. Not sure why they do.

here is the one
.This one can decrypt fully encryptes videos or images.  Decrypts full images in ms how ever does not work to decrypt partially encrypted videos.

```
  public void img_decrypt(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
    try {
        // Bytes read from in will be decrypted
        in = new CipherInputStream(in, dcipher);

        // Read in the decrypted bytes and write the cleartext to out
        int numRead = 0;


        while ((numRead = in.read(buf)) >= 0 ) {

            out.write(buf, 0, numRead);
        }


        out.close();
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
    }
}
```

And here is the other. This takes forever to run. Will decrypt fully encrypted images or partially encrypted videos.

```
    public void decrypt(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
    try {
        // Bytes written to out will be decrypted
        AppendableOutputStream out_append = new AppendableOutputStream(out);
        System.out.println(ecipher.getOutputSize(1024*1024));
        OutputStream out_d = new CipherOutputStream(out_append, dcipher);

        // Read in the decrypted bytes and write the cleartext to out
        int numRead = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int max = 1024;
        boolean out_d_closed = false;

        while ((numRead = in.read(buf, 0, max)) > 0) {
            count += numRead;
            if(count <= ecipher.getOutputSize(1024*1024)){
                out_d.write(buf, 0, numRead);
                out_d_closed = false;
                // last encryption pass, close buffer and fix max
                if(count == ecipher.getOutputSize(1024*1024)){
                    // fix reading 1k in case max was decreased
                    max = 1024;
                    out_d.close();
                    out_d_closed = true;
                }
                // if next read will go over a meg, read less than 1k
                else if(count + max > ecipher.getOutputSize(1024*1024))
                    max = ecipher.getOutputSize(1024*1024) - count;
            }
            // past the first meg, don't decrypt
            else{
                out.write(buf, 0, numRead);
            }

        }
        if(!out_d_closed){

            out_d.close();

        }
        out.close();
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

Because the decrypt() method takes SOOOOOO long to decrypt a 100KB file, the device asks me to abort or wait.

If I use img_decrypt() it works in not time at all. Which to me makes no sense they are doing the same thing.

Im trying to use decrypt() to decrypt the first MB of the video.

On the computer everything works fine.

Any thoughts might be helpful.

Both methods work for decrypting a fully encrypted file, decrypt() take way too long though.

One more thing. decrypt() decrypts the data on the write. img_decrypt() decrypts the data on the read. No idea if that effects anything.

Thanks

Comment: Just curious: if the ugly, confusing code is also slow, why are you bothering with it?

Comment: AppendableOutputStream out_append = new AppendableOutputStream(out);  Overrites the close() so that it doesn't close the parent. BTW

Comment: After lots of testing. out_d.write() is what is slowing it down.  But in the other method out.write is way faster.  Save video being fully decrypted with img_decrypted() method works in around 4 seconds.  Decrypted 1 MB with the other one take around 20.

Comment: UPDATE. out_d.write is slow because of the AppendableOutputStream()  I use it so that the parent close doesn't get closed..... hmmm

Comment: If anyone cares. FilterOutputStream is implemented wrong. Sun wrote the write method wrong. Have to override the write for it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone cares. FilterOutputStream is implemented wrong. Sun wrote the write method wrong. Have to override the write for it to work properly.

Comment: You mean that "the `write` method of `FilterOutputStream` calls the `write` method of one argument *on each byte* to output," and that "this method does *not* call the `write` method of its underlying input stream with the same arguments; subclasses of `FilterOutputStream` should provide a more efficient implementation of this method?" These points are made clearly in the documentation, so I believe it is more honest to say that you used the API incorrectly than to say, "Sun wrote the `write` method wrong."

Comment: @erickson from the documentation "The class FilterOutputStream itself simply overrides all methods of OutputStream with versions that pass all requests to the underlying output stream. Subclasses of FilterOutputStream may further override some of these methods as well as provide additional methods and fields."

Comment: the documentation claims that the filteredoutputstream class does nothing other than pass the calls through to the underlying output stream, but instead it tampers with the functioning of the underlying object and documents that it has, presumably intentionally, made byte array write calls inefficient.